# How to use Split method in java

Tags: java, split

i use under code for split phone number list "0771234567", i need to get only "771234567" number without first part. i mean without "0" and need to ad "94". but i got out put under format
Output

```
94
9477*******
94
9470*******
94
9471*******
```

i got output like this

[image: Out put result]

```
String s1 = "771234561";
String[] Phone = s1.split("0", 2);                
for (int i = 0; i < Phone.length; i++) {
System.out.println("94"+Phone[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to split is the logic stays the same, from `0771234567` just remove the first char and add `94` before

```
String s1 = "0771234567";
String value = "94" + s1.substring(1);
```

---

When you split over a delimiter, you get the parts that are before/between/after this delimiter

So split over `0` in `0771234567` gives you `{'', '771234567}` so when iterating over this, you have one empty box, giving the `94` alone

Comment: First of all i like to thank for helping me. but i try that code then pop-up "java.lang.stringindexoutofboundsexception: string index out of range "-1" exception. So can you plese help.

Comment: pop up some exception but ok, if you can please tell other way. by-the way thanks a lot

Comment: @Deen what do you do, you normally can't have the exception, except if the string is empty